# meaning of the word " der Abstecher" and its usage

Tags: meaning

can you explain what exactly the word "der Abstecher" means? is it used in daily life often? and can you build up some example sentences using it?

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Abstecher

Comment: a dictionary doesn't let me know in what context I can use it and whether it is a commonly used word. that is why I asked for example sentences and asked whether it is used often. the example in wiktionary was helpful thanks

Comment: Fragen "What does xy *exactly* mean ..." sind so sinnlos wie häufig. Wörter sind oft mehrdeutig oder unscharf. Je angemessener die Antwort, umso vager. Wenn es nicht nach hier und da mäandert wurde das Habitat nicht durchmessen. Exact kann aber nur eine knappe Antwort sein, wenn ein Wort keine breite Anwendung findet. Dann tut es aber das Wort, das man im Wörterbuch findet.

Comment: ı am not asking for a one word definition by saying what it exactly means. i think it is clear that ı looked the word up from the dictionary and trying to see in which context to use it. anyways. someone just posted a very useful answer.

Comment: @Taylan By just reading your question it is not clear, whether or not you did look up the word already and what exactly remained unclear. Unfortunately we have many posts that lack minimal effort, hence the harsh feedback. Don't take it personal and please add to your questions some more details about what you've figured out already and what exactly remains unclear.

Comment: alright, I will try to formulate the questions better the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Der Abstecher, den Lea und ich gemacht haben, hat uns drei Stunden gekostet": The detour Lea and l made cost us three hours.

"Ich habe auf dem Heimweg einen kleinen Abstecher gemacht und Milch gekauft": I made a detour on the way home and bought milk.

Der Abstecher means something like Umweg, but with a specific "halfway-location" you also want to reach; for example, you could make a Abstecher to the bakery, while on the way to your boyfriend's house and bring your bf something from the bakery; however if you were to simply take the scenic route on the way to your boyfriends, that would be a Umweg.

The difference between the two is so small that using Umweg in both cases would be quite normal, however using Abstecher in the second case would be strange.

I'd say you could use Abstecher in everyday conversation without raising any questions (I have done it) as it is a pretty "normal" word but a lot of people use Umweg instead of Abstecher.

Since "abstechen" as a verb means to kill someone through stabbing, please don't use the verb. I am not kidding, look it up!

(Therefore "Der Abstecher" as a person would be a murderer that stabs his victims and isn't very good at codenames, but I just assumed you meant the other thing.)

Comment: Let me add Umweg is more disruptive, e.g. it's an extra way you must go because of a closed road or to pick up someone. In contrast an Abstecher is more like something spontaneous or voluntary such as we don't yet want to go home / we still have some time left / something nice to see isn't far from here - so let's make an Abstecher to xy.

Comment: The term *Abstecher* used for a murderer is so uncommon if used at all that we do not have to take it into account here.